# ServiceStack/SOAP generating compatible WSDL

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

I need to prop up a bunch of services that are SOAP-only but I am having trouble defining the services in such a way that existing clients can consume these services with little or no change. The issues I am strugging with are, 1. getting the POST value correct, 2. the SOAPAction, 3. Including the datatypes, and 4. having it include all the child data members.

Consider this simple service that searches for stores:

---- REQUEST ----

```
POST /services-1.0/Store.asmx
SOAPAction: http://example.com/Services/LookupStores
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: string
Host: string

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <LookupStores xmlns="http://example.com/Services">
      <AuthenticationID>string</AuthenticationID>
      <NameMatch>string</NameMatch>
    </LookupStores>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

----  RESPONSE -----

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: string

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <LookupStoresResponse xmlns="http://example.com/Services">
      <LookupStoresResult>
        <StoreList>
          <StoreData>
            <Number>string</Number>
            <Name>string</Name>
          </StoreData>
          <StoreData>
            <Number>string</Number>
            <Name>string</Name>
          </StoreData>
        </StoreList>
        <ResponseCode>string</ResponseCode>
        <ResponseMessage>string</ResponseMessage>
        <ExtendedResponseMessage>string</ExtendedResponseMessage>
      </LookupStoresResult>
    </LookupStoresResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The service code that hopefully mimics it:

```
public class Store : Service
{
    public LookupStoresResponse Post(LookupStores request)
    {
        return new LookupStoresResponse();
    }
}

[DataContract(Namespace="http://example.com/Services")]
public class LookupStores
{
    [DataMember]
    string AuthenticationID { get { return ""; } set { } }
    [DataMember]
    string NameMatch;
}

 [DataContract]
public class LookupStoresResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    List<StoreData> LookupStoresResult;
}

[DataContract]
public class LookupStoresResult
{
    [DataMember]
    List<StoreData> StoreList;
}

[DataContract]
public class StoreData
{
    [DataMember]
    string Number;
    [DataMember]
    string Name;
}
```

Yields:

```
POST /soap11 HTTP/1.1 
Host: localhost 
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: LookupStores

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>

<LookupStores xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://example.com/Services">
  <AuthenticationID />
  <NameMatch i:nil="true" />
</LookupStores>

    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>

<LookupStoresResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EagleServices.Services">
  <LookupStoresResult i:nil="true" />
</LookupStoresResponse>

    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```